# Computing row-sum scaled unsigned Stirling nos. of the 1st kind

Tags: co.combinatorics, approximation-algorithms

As the title suggests, I would like to compute probability vectors with elements proportional to (unsigned) Stirling numbers of the first kind by row. For easy reference, here is the [Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind).

[image]

For example, I'd like an efficient algorithm to return $p_6 \approx \frac{[120, \;274, \;225, \;85, \;15, \;1]}{720}$ when $n=6$. Previous MO questions have considered computing Sterling numbers, for example [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72854/stirling-number-of-first-kind-implementation) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34151/simple-efficient-representation-of-stirling-numbers-of-the-first-kind). In my case, however, a reasonable approximation would suffice. I suppose that the scaling by row-sums might actually make the problem easier, as many of the elements decay rapidly with the row number $n$. It is not immediately obvious how to find such an approximation however, so I'm hoping someone here has a reference or some insight to share.

The approach of this [paper](http://oai.cwi.nl/oai/asset/2304/2304A.pdf) might prove useful, but I have not digested it as yet.

---

This came up for me in a the course of a project concerning de Finetti theorems and kernel density estimation procedures, and is well outside my wheelhouse.  I would be happy to hear that this question is trivial for combinatorics specialists. I have also tried the usual Google tactics, but precisely because there is a wealth of information about Stirling numbers I have found my question hard to address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a reasonably good approximation using bounds given in a [tech report](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCAQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatistics.berkeley.edu%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Ftech-reports%2F453.ps.Z&ei=PrxJVPiGOYjLsASyyIL4DQ&usg=AFQjCNHjevPhTst2F8F8T00xArtC3yuYNQ&sig2=lWq2dQUdHMLJwV5AAg44SA&bvm=bv.77880786,d.cWc) of Jim Pitman.

Starting on page 13 an example is worked out which computes bounds on ratios of row-adjacent Stirling numbers using stable and efficient polygamma evaluations; see expressions (33) and (34) specifically.